# Shiryaev - random walk - problem with proving $E\left[S_{\tau_{n}}-\tau_{n}\cdot E\xi_{1}\right]^{2}=\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\cdot E\tau_{n}$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

In order to prove that the mean duration of the random walk $m\left(x\right)$ is finite for all $x\in\left(A,B\right)$ (e.g. $x$ is the starting position of a particle). For the case $x=0$ the author introduces an equation:
$$S_{\tau_{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}S_{k}\left(\omega\right)I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\left(\omega\right)$$

$\xi_{1},\xi_{2},\dots,\xi_{n}$ is a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables.

$P\left(\xi_{i}=1\right)=p$, $P\left(\xi_{i}=-1\right)=q$, $p\neq q$

$S_{0}=0$, $S_{k}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\xi_{i}$

$\tau_{n}$ is stopping time.

In page 93, equation (34):
$$\mathrm{E}\left[S_{\tau_{n}}-\tau_{n}\cdot\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right]^{2}=\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\cdot\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}$$

which said to be proved similarly to previous method, in the case of $p=q$, introduced in previous page. But, I could not have the result above and stuck:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{E}\left[S_{\tau_{n}}-\tau_{n}\cdot\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right]^{2} & =\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[S_{k}^{2}-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\left(S_{k}-S_{n}+S_{n}\right)^{2}-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[2S_{n}\left(S_{k}-S_{n}\right)+\left(S_{n}-S_{k}\right)^{2}-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{E}\left(S_{n}-S_{k}\right)^{2}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{E}\left(S_{n}-S_{k}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\left(n-k\right)\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}+\left(n-k\right)^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]\mathrm{E}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}-n\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}+\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(n^{2}-2nk+k^{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}P\left(\tau_{n}=k\right)+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\left(\mathrm{E}S_{n}^{2}-\mathrm{Var}S_{n}\right)+\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(n^{2}-2nk+k^{2}\right)\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}P\left(\tau_{n}=k\right)+\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[-2kS_{k}\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}+k^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\right]I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\left(\mathrm{E}S_{n}\right)^{2}+\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-n^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}+2n\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{2}P\left(\tau_{n}=k\right)+\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k^{2}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }-2\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}kS_{k}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\left(\mathrm{E}S_{n}\right)^{2}+\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-n^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}+2n\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-2\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}kS_{k}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =n^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}+\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-n^{2}\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}+2n\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-2\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}kS_{k}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
 & =\mathrm{Var}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}+2n\left(\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\right)^{2}\mathrm{E}\tau_{n}-2\mathrm{E}\xi_{1}\mathrm{E}\sum_{k=0}^{n}kS_{k}I_{\left\{ \tau_{n}=k\right\} }\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Have you thought about applying the optional stopping theorem?

Comment: @saz: In this book, the section about random walk is just introduction, and has not introduced optional stopping theorem (I don't know about it yet, and it seems that this is part of about chapter VII of this book).